# Application Loader warning, cordova webview

Tags: phonegap-build, ionic-v1

I successfully submit the ipa file to the App Store using Application Loader.
But it shows the warning - The app references non-public selectors in Payload ...:
"_setAlwaysRunsAtForegroundPriority"

Note: I'm using the ionic-v1 and phonegap build service.

Warning related - cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Comment: have you got solution?

Comment: Yes. Please update to the latest. https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/209

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to the latest.
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/209
the fixes are detailed in this plugins docs 'migrating to v4'